# Kohana 3.1 ORM - Conditional Parameters

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I am trying to achieve a very simple goal, however it does not seem to be working. I wish to use Kohana's ORM and conditionally add certain parameters.

For instance:

```
$query = ORM::factory('user')
  ->where('foo', '=', 'bar');

if (isset($some_var))
  $query->where('field', '=', $some_var);

$query->find_all();
```

One would think this should work, but all I get from `$query` is a big fat nothing. Any suggestions I would greatly appreciate! Thanks.

**EDIT:**

The simple example on this Kohana page even shows a similar query:
http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/orm/examples/simple

...But even when I create a 'user' model instance and then try to `find_all()` in a separate statement, I get nothing.

**This works:**

```
$query = ORM::factory('user')->find_all();
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
$query = ORM::factory('user');
$query->find_all();
```

Possible bug??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example that works, you are assigning the value returned from find_all() to $query. While in the example that is not working, you are not assigning the value returned by find_all() at all.

[kohana framework](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/ORM#find_all)

```
$query = ORM::factory('user');
$result = $query->find_all(); 
// you may now loop over $result
```

When you look over the api, you will see that find() and find_all() work differently.

Comment: My god, I can't believe I missed that. Ugh. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine, as `ORM::where` method returns ORM object, so there is no problem with method chaining. You should look for the errors in other place (perhaps your `$some_var` is set but may be empty, therefore your condition may look different then expected). I'd try with this small change:

```
if (!empty($some_var))
  $query->where('field', '=', $some_var);
```

Comment: I wish that was just the problem. But when I eliminate the "if" line, I get the same result. It's like when the query is split up, it doesn't work anymore. I get the same result as well when I use `DB::select`.

Comment: Well, all I can say is that it always worked and works for me, so the problem MUST be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: If my problem isn't in this code, perhaps it's in the way I'm trying to access the data? In my view file, I have a `foreach ($query as $user)` loop, and in there I am trying to access the data via `$user->first_name`. Do I need to do something else first in order to make that work? I don't know why it should make a difference, but at this point I don't know what else it could be. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Best you could do is to post whole controller/view/model files